# Why wont my HealthBar visual decrease when i interact with an enemy collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have recently started creating a c# game due to it being a mandatory assignment in my computer science course however i am new to c# and have hit a bump. I have written a Healthbar script so that when my player collides with a gameobject tagged "Enemy" the players health should reduce by 20. However when i press play the health bar visual did not decrease as it should. Like i said i am new to c# so im not too sure how to fix it. I have searched many tutorials however they all gave me the same suggestion of checking to make sure the inspector window of my player and enemy is correct.

After making sure everyting is linked up properly including making the player box collider to " is trigger" and then adding a capsule collider so that it still interacts like a solid object, the code i wrote still didnt work, and whenever i hit my enemy which i tagged as "Enemy" the health bar visual did not change/decrease. I thought that maybe it was just the visual and my health was actually reducing, so to check this i added debugging code to produce a message in the console whether the OnTriggerEnter code was working properly and to my surprise it did not work. I added multiple other debugging code lines as well and none of them showed that anything was working.

This is my player script, giving my player health and allowing the TakeDamage code to run if i enter the enemies collider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
public int maxHealth = 100;
public int currentHealth;

    public HealthBar healthBar;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        if (healthBar != null)
        {
            healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        }
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
    
    void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        
        if (currentHealth < 0)
        {
    
            // Trigger game over event
            Debug.Log("Game over!");
        }
        
        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }
    
    // This function is called when the player collides with an enemy
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision detected!");
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            // Decrease the player's health by a certain amount
            TakeDamage(20);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my healthbar script which should update and decrease based on the value after the TakeDamage line is executed upon collding with the enemy, however no matter what i try, it doesnt seem to update, nor do any debug areas appear in my console, showing that the script isnt detecting the collision between me and my enemy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Slider slider;
    public Gradient gradient;
    public Image fill;
    
    public void SetMaxHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.maxValue = health;
        slider.value = health;
    
        fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(1f);
    }
    
    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.value = health;
    
        fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(slider.normalizedValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: isnt slider values 0-1 ? so you might need to convert the helath value to a %

Comment: @JoshAdams i have looked at the slider values and changed it to 100 and activated whole numbers so that it now goes from 0-100, yet it still isnt working.

Comment: can do something like healthBar.FillAmount(current health/ max health)  they both need to be floats though

Comment: @JoshAdams where abouts would i implemet this into my script?

Comment: played around a bit with your scripts.  Do you have rigid bodies on your objects?  when I added the rigid body I was able to get the debugs to fire

Comment: @JoshAdams yeah my player and enemy both have a rigid body on them, im making a topdown game so the gravity is set to 0 and the collision is on discrete, i assume neither of these will have an affect though right? im not sure why the debugs arent appearing in the console.

Comment: @jordanH16 do you have the "IsTrigger" box checked to true on your object that has the Player.cs script attached? Are you able to share the repo link, it'd be helpful to know the meta data for the objects to understand exactly where you might be missing something.

Comment: @JoshAdams apologies for what may seem like a stupid question but like i said im new to all of this, what is a repo link and how would i go about sharing it?